# Can I get a visa to Germany outside my home county as a student in the USA?

Tags: visas, germany, europe

I'm a Kenyan college student currently in the United States on an F1 Visa but I would like to go to Germany to visit my family in the summer of next year, can I apply for a German Visa in the USA ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you not only can, but actually must apply for the German visa in the USA. The general rule is that you should apply for a German visa at your place of residence. Your citizenship is for that decision not relevant.